# Length function C# Not Working

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have simple script to display the length of a string in HTML field using Javascript. The length function which I use is not working fine. But I am unable to sort out the solution. Please advise.

```
 @foreach (var val in ViewData["Students"] as List<Students>)
    {
       var state = @val.state;  // its working fine
        if ( (@state.length == 7))    // its not working length function fails
           {
             <p> I am : @state : with length :  @state.length</p>
           }
     }
```

Comment: Why do you need the `@` after `var state...`? Does `if ( (state.length == 7))` not work?

Comment: it does nt work either way

Comment: What's the error and what does `console.log(state)` and `console.log(@state)` show you in the debugger console?

Comment: I sense this isn't Vanilla JavaScript...

Comment: @state shows me the actual string inside the variable. state just shows me the variable name "State" . state.length fails to run.

Comment: Can we remove or change the JavaScript tag?

Comment: i am using other functions like state.split( ':') as well. thats working fine. i dnt knw i am missing somethign with length part

Comment: not working in here.

Comment: .length is not working in any condition. @val.state displays the Value inside variable val. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are programming in C# using Razor, this is not a Javascript issue.

If `state` is a Collection, try using property `.Count` instead :

```
@foreach (var val in ViewData["Students"] as List<Students>)
 {
       var state = @val.state;  // its working fine
       if ( (@state.Count == 7))    // its not working length function fails
       {
             <p> I am : @state : with length :  @state.Count</p>
       }
  }
```

Comment: No this is not the case. state has just one value from the collection. its a foreach loop. Also, I am doing front end in HTML + JS . C# is backend which is not the point in this case. Thanks

Comment: @BaseerUlHassan then why is the code in your question Razer not javascript?

Comment: @BaseerUlHassan Please take 5 minutes to understand what technologies you are using https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp 
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewdata-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: bviale@ I used JS. but for couple of fields. it was inevitable . Razor was last resort